# How do I test a addon without compressing?

Tags: add-on

I'm making a simple addon which has some .py files.(**init**, ui, operator, and so on)
Must Blender needs a compressing addon file to install?

Can I test a addon quickly from files directly, without compressing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just place them inside your Blender version's AppData add-ons folder, unzipped.

All zipped add-ons that are installed are automatically unzipped and placed in that location anyhow.

The zipped folder is merely a convenience method.

Comment: Thank you for kind answering!